# What is the minimal distance between several combined sets of coordinates?

Tags: geometry

Though I am a math noob, I am trying to answer a real life problem with a math solution. I have simplified the problem in a way that it's easy to work with. It is definately possible there already exists a solution for this problem that I am unaware of.

I have several sets of coordinates, for example (each row is a different set):

- [1,1], [2,2]
- [1,2], [2,1]
- [2,3], [3,3]
- [3,3], [3,4]
- [3,5], [5,5]
- [4,5], [5,5]

I want to combine these sets so, that I'm left the least possible amount of sets, but have a maximum of X (in this example 3) sets combined. For example:

- [1,1], [2,2], [1,2], [2,1], [2,3], [3,3]
- [3,3], [3,4], [3,5], [5,5], [4,5], [5,5]

I cannot split a set, just combine different sets. The distance in a set is the smallest line through all of the coordinates in the set. How can I best combine the sets so, that the total distance of the combined sets is minimized?

Any points in the direction of a solution (maybe there is a model for this problem I'm not aware of), or a solution itself is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the smallest line through all of the coordinates in the set" ? In general, an arbitrary set of point will *not* all lie on the same straight line. So can your "line" be a curve ? Or maybe a network of straight line segments joined together in some manner ? Or something else ?

Comment: I don't know the correct words, but for example, imagine 3 flags random on a parking lot and the goal is to touch each one of them with the minimal distance walked. So straight lines between coordinates and all coordinates must be connected.

Comment: When you say "smallest line" I think you mean "shortest path". However, it seems you want to optimize two things at the same time: smallest number of sets and shortest total path length. You generally can't do that. You need to select one or the other or some combination of the two, e.g. $n D$, where $n$ is number of sets and $D$ is total path length.

Comment: Shortest path sounds exactly like what I want. the smallest number of sets is not really what I want to optimize, that's just a variable that can differ. But for the example, 3 sets combined is okay. So the shortest total path length is what I seek.